# Keycard door not working properly when putted in replicated storage

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a key card door but it don't work when I put it in replicatesStorage (it is a gamepass key) can somebody help me it only work when put in starterPack ** here is code:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent.Name == "Clearance1" then
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        script.Parent.Transparency = 0.5
        wait(0.5)
        script.Parent.CanCollide = true
        script.Parent.Transparency = 0
    end
end)
```

Comment: It is being given at a localscript at StarterScreenGui

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, it's a little unclear _what_ isn't working. What is "it" that is being put into ReplicatedStorage? Is the door itself in ReplicatedStorage? Is the gamepass key stored in ReplicatedStorage? Is this code in a LocalScript or a Script? Could you add some more details to your question about what it should be doing, and what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

is the key being given on the client? (with a localscript)

edit: maybe try something like

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
  player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
    if game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):UserOwnsGamePassAsync(player.UserId,0000000) then
      game.ReplicatedStorage.KeyCard:Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
    end
  end)
end)
```

Comment: It is being given at a localscript at StarterScreenGui

Comment: if you give stuff on the client, it won't interact with the server properly. you shouldn't give game pass stuff on the client. i'll edit the response with an example of what you could do