# Keycard door not working when i put the keycard at replicates storage

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a key card door but it don't work when I put it in replicatesStorage (it is a gamepass key) can somebody help me it only work when put in starterPack it is currently being given with a localScript at StartGui ** here is code:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent.Name == "Clearance1" then
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        script.Parent.Transparency = 0.5
        wait(0.5)
        script.Parent.CanCollide = true
        script.Parent.Transparency = 0
    end
end)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycard door not working properly when putted in replicated storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382624/keycard-door-not-working-properly-when-putted-in-replicated-storage)

Answer (score 0):

StarterPack is already replicated, in a way.
If you use ReplicatedStorage, you'll have to add it to PlayerInstance.Backpack.

Also, `script.Parent.Touched` is server-side only.

If you wanna access the player's backpack, you can use `game.Players.PLAYERNAME.Backpack`

The way you're doing this is actually not a very good idea. (no offense)
I would recommend leaving the item inside the StarterPack. If you really don't want to, you can programmatically do it by putting it in their Backpack. Like this:

```lua
-- Server script
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player) -- Runs when a player joins the game
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function() -- Runs when that player respawns or their character loads
        local itemCopy = game.ReplicatedStorage.Clearance1:Clone() -- Creates a copy of the item
        itemCopy.Parent = player.Backpack -- Puts the item in the player's backpack (inventory)
    end)
end)
```

What that code does is: Every time the player spawns, it clones the item and puts it in their inventory.

Now to check if the user has the item when they touch the door, you can do something like this:

```lua
-- Server script
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(part) -- Activates when a part touches the doorf
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent) -- Gets a player from the part that touched
    if player and player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Clearance1") then -- Makes sure there is a player, and the player has the keycard in their inventory
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false -- Makes the part uncollidable
        script.Parent.Transparency = 0.5 -- Sets the part to have transparency
        wait(0.5) -- Waits half a second
        script.Parent.CanCollide = true -- Makes the part collidable
        script.Parent.Transparency = 0 -- Makes the part not transparent
    end
end)
```

Every time the part is touched, it checks if it's a player. If it is, it checks if the player has the item. If so, it runs the code.